# Redirect from http to https on HEROKU

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, redirect

I have a reactjs frontend server and a backend ruby on rails server. Both of them are hosted on Heroku.

My domain name is on GoDaddy and i am paying a version on Heroku (for my frontend server) to have a ssl (Automated Certificate Management (ACM)).

I can access my domain name on the https protocol but also on the http protocol

I would like to redirect all connections to the website from http to https.

I tried multiple things:

- Cloudflare but that didn't work out
- https_only in my static.json of my reactjs server
- force_ssl=true on my ruby on rails server

Nothing is working.

What are your advice to solve that kind of problems ? I don't know if i should solve that in the reactjs server (no info about that on google) or on godaddy (apparently that is not working with heroku) or on the rails server (i don't think so because it's the backend server)...

I am looking forward to have a better understanding of the DNS thing but it is not easy, have you some tutorial to share with me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use the ["Always use HTTPS"-Feature](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-make-your-site-https-only/) from Cloudflare for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apparently it should work but i still had other problems because of the change of dns. Do you know how much times it takes so that the "Alwayse use https" is working ? Generally i have troubles because i don't know if i have made something wrong or if i just need to wait one day or so